# How to initialize and train an SVM with rootSIFT features in python

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, scikit-learn

I have a CBIR system set up in python utilizing OpenCV. I have successfully extracted the keypoints and descriptors, clustered them using k-means to create a codebook, and have generated histograms describing images based on this codebook. I would like to know how I can use these histograms generated on the last line of this code to train an SVM, or if I am going about this in the wrong way.

```
import argparse
import glob
import cv2
import numpy
import pickle
import base64
from scipy.cluster.vq import *
from cassandra.cluster import Cluster

def compute(imagePath, eps=1e-7)
    sift = cv2.xfeatures2d.SIFT_create()
    image = cv2.imread(imagePath, 0)

    kp, des = sift.detectAndCompute(image, None)

    if des is not None:
        kp, des = sift.compute(image, kp)

        if len(kp) == 0:
            return ([], None)

        des /= (des.sum(axis=1, keepdims=True) + eps)
        des = numpy.sqrt(des)

        des = whiten(des)

        return kp, des

for imagePath in dataset :
    kp,des = compute(imagePath)

    codes, distortion = vq(des, codebook)
    hist, bins = numpy.histogram(codes, K)
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [sklearn.svm](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.SVC.html)  and how SVM classification works [here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/svm.html#svm-classification).
Maybe you can just follow the [Bag of Words](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bag-of-words_model_in_computer_vision) common procedure, which means that for each image feature (histogram) you should select the nearest codeword of the dictionary (according to some measure of feature distance/similarity).